# Setting release version in Delphi VCL XE6

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I can change the release version from 0.9 to 1.0 in Delphi VCL, but it won't stick, and reverts back to 0.9 when I re-enter the Options / Version Info. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact steps that you are doing. Details do matter.

Comment: Do you save your project after changing the Version Info ? (by the way, the  Version Info are different for Debug and Release).

Comment: I've never found that the IDE facility works properly. Instead I write my own tooling as part of my build process.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to create your own version resource and include it.

This makes you completely independant of the delphi version information settings and makes sure that it is always consistant also when compiling from the command line without using the .dproj file and you can use it for multiple exes if your project contains more than one.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782328/how-to-define-application-version-in-one-place-for-multiple-applications/11782584#11782584) please find detailed information on how to do it. It is easy.